# Access user's OpenID info in templates on Google app engine (tipfy)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, middleware, tipfy

I'm using the OpenID authentication that's built into Google app engine and trying to make the currently signed in user's information **automatically** available in templates.

Doing it manually might be something like:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from tipfy import RequestHandler
from tipfy.ext.jinja2 import render_response

def WhateverHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        return render_response('template_name.html', user=user)
        # great, now I can use {{ user.nickname }} or whatever in the template
```

I don't want to write this code in every request handler so expecting to be able to add some kind of middleware to take care of it (and I'm mostly guessing here):

```
from google.appengine.api import users

class GoogleUsersMiddleware(object)

    def post_dispatch(self, handler, response):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        # now somehow add user to the response?

        return response
```

Any ideas?  I've tried looking at how tipfy's SessionMiddleware works but don't quite get it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subclass of RequestHandler that retrieves the current user automatically on `__init__`. Also you can add methods to that subclass to customize template rendering.  I don't think Middleware is the right solution for this problem.

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from tipfy import RequestHandler
from tipfy.ext.jinja2 import render_response

class UserPageHandler(RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, app, request):
        super(UserPageHandler, self).__init__(app, request)

        self.user = users.get_current_user()

    def user_response(self, template_name):
        return render_response(template_name, user=self.user)

def WhateverHandler(UserPageHandler):
    def get(self):
        return self.user_response('template_name.html')
```

Comment: This looks like it'll work fine. Thanks. I was thinking of django and got confused between middleware and context processors.